# iOS Scatter core Plot,how to join two points by a line?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, core-plot, scatter-plot

For example, if the plot has five data points say from 1-5 on x-axis. But i want to plot points only at 1,3 & 5 by skipping 2 & 4. I've been plot the points at 1,3,5. But i'm not able to connect these three points by a line. Can anyone help me to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

this is the code i'm using

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSInteger valueCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];

    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if ((index < valueCount) && ((index%3)==0)) {
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:(index)];
            }
        break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] == YES)//graph1{
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolAAPL] objectAtIndex:index];
            } else
            if (([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] == YES) && ((index%3)==0))//graph2 {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolGOOG] objectAtIndex:index];
            } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] == YES)//graph3 {
                return [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] monthlyPrices:CPDTickerSymbolMSFT] objectAtIndex:index];
            }
        break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber notANumber];
}
```

here there is three different graphs and the graph2 will plot points only when index % 3 is equal to 0. Now i want to join all the points plotted by this graph2. This piece of code is taken from raywenderlich core plot example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To plot only three points, have `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` return three (3). The x-values don't have to be equal to the index.

```
Index    x     y
-----------------------
  0      1     y0
  1      3     y1
  2      5     y2
```